# openssl_encrypt gives different results

Tags: php, encryption

With the introduction of GDPR it is advisable to start encrypting sensitive data entered in your database. I intended to equip myself with a couple of experiences
The doubt is fast enough, changing servers or updating the php to a longer version, the algorithms are copied by php.net and well referenced by many users should they be obsolete and therefore no longer supported? I would find myself with a lot of data on a database without being able to do anything about it.
I'm currently using the next code.

When I use the secured_encrypt function several times, I get different results every time. How is it possible?

Thank you!

```
    <?php

public function secured_encrypt($data){
$first_key = base64_decode($this -> FIRSTKEY);
$second_key = base64_decode($this -> SECONDKEY);   

$method = "aes-256-cbc";   
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_length);

$first_encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method,$first_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA ,$iv);   
$second_encrypted = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);

$output = base64_encode($iv.$second_encrypted.$first_encrypted);   
return $output;       
}


public function secured_decrypt($input){
$first_key = base64_decode($this -> FIRSTKEY);
$second_key = base64_decode($this -> SECONDKEY);           
$mix = base64_decode($input);

$method = "aes-256-cbc";   
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);

$iv = substr($mix,0,$iv_length);
$second_encrypted = substr($mix,$iv_length,64);
$first_encrypted = substr($mix,$iv_length+64);

$data = openssl_decrypt($first_encrypted,$method, $first_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$second_encrypted_new = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);

if (hash_equals($second_encrypted,$second_encrypted_new))
return $data;

return false;
}  
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean with i get different results?

Comment: I mean that for the same string (f.e. "123") I get 
"Oagemf2Z50c3dYYToZdecD0bkj9GHUtPjls5N7qfrak=",
"pzWRDHhaqhGOiZVFG8MdgWqdwmo41tcgmX/6DwFbaJw=",
"h3otFZ2HaVoK73rk94o/THqxuw2CrMerxCNk8C5ojMU="
and so on...

Comment: CBC is `probabilistic encryption` that requires [unpredictable IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure-against-chosen-plaintext-atta). CBC mode requires padding that is vulnerable to [padding oracle attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/how-does-a-padding-oracle-attack-work). Proper use of CBC mode prevents comparison on encrypted data, and has no integrity, And never use ECB. You may use AES-GCM(_SIV) mode if applicable that is auehanticated encryption you will have authentication, integrity and confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the initialization vector with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`

Comment: This makes perfectly sense. Ho could I put a fixed initialization vector?
Is it sure enough?
If not, how could I look for something into a mysql database if every ecrypted string is different?

Comment: That is the point of the IV - to make the data different with each encryption - to make it more secure ! Without the IV, your encrypted data are leaking information.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these informations!
The point is that I don't know how to handle the SQL query. If I have the fiscal code of a person, f.e. "123456abc" and I need to find his row into the database, I won't be able to use a query like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE cf = 'encrypted($fiscal_code))'"... 
How should I do?

Comment: First check if you really need to encrypt that information. If so, hash the contents and use it as an ID (in which you can query/find it later).

pseudo: 
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE cf_hash = hash($fiscal_code)`
/
`decrypt('SELECT cf_content FROM users WHERE cf_hash = hash($fiscal_code)')`